# Angular 8 multiple Search Filter (Pipe) not working

Tags: angular, angular8

My Search Filter is not working as I have one Input Field for Search in which I want to Search by Employee Number or Employee Name

My Search Filter Code (Pipe)

```
   import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'searchEmployee'
})
export class SearchEmployeePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: any, filter: any, isAnd: boolean): any {
    if (filter && Array.isArray(items)) {
      let filterKeys = Object.keys(filter);
      if (isAnd) {
        return items.filter(item =>
          filterKeys.reduce((memo, keyName) =>
            (memo && new RegExp(filter[keyName], 'gi').test(item[keyName])) || filter[keyName] === "", true));
      } else {
        return items.filter(item => {
          return filterKeys.some((keyName) => {
            console.log(new RegExp(filter[keyName], 'gi').test(item[keyName]) || filter[keyName])
            return new RegExp(filter[keyName], 'gi').test(item[keyName]) || filter[keyName] === "";
          });
        });
      }
    } else {
      return items;
    }
  };
}
```

My html is

```
<div class="search-employee-input-div">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search Employee" class="employee-list-searchbox" [(ngModel)]="employeeSearchQuery" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" />
  </div>

<li formArrayName="Employees" *ngFor="let emp of payrollProcessingList.Employees | searchEmployee: { EmployeeID: employeeSearchQuery, FullName: employeeSearchQuery }: false; let i = index;" class="emp-li-loop"></li>
```

Comment: Do you get an error?

Comment: share payrollProcessingList.Employees data

Comment: no it always return me the first object

Comment: [{EmployeeName: 'Dutton, Felix', Employee Number: 100002}]

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jgpkzd

Comment: Please check stackblitz link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR;** In order to make your pipe work, you will need to make it `pure: false` and you should not be doing that !

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'searchEmployee',
  pure: false
})
```

Pipes reason is performance, impure pipes are a performance issue. Angular used to have a filter pipe but not anymore [angular.io](https://angular.io/guide/pipes) :

> Angular doesn't have a FilterPipe or an OrderByPipe for reasons explained in the Appendix of this page.

Try to use RxJS to implement the filtering feature.

Comment: Thnx for reply, but it dosent work, actually my filter always return the first object

Comment: You probably also need to pass multiple parameters instead of an object, the object reference doesn't change and pipe doesn't get executed. Also the real answer is "don't use pipes for filtering, it's bad"

Comment: Stackblitz link please check

Comment: it always return me the first object

Comment: If u have any alternate solution please help me out of this

Comment: The filtering issue comes from `payrollProcessingList.Employees[i]` remplace it with `emp` => `<div class="emp-number-val-div">{{emp.EmployeeID}}</div>`

Comment: I woudl suggest using RxJS instead of a pipe, here is an example : https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-58135422

Comment: Thanks  a lot, One more thing is that I want to search by employee id or Employee Name how can I achieve that with rxjs, currently it only search with employee name

Comment: You need to update the `search` function in the `AppComponent` class.